# What are page up/ page down keys on Macbook for TextMate?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, textmate

In other apps I use Command-UpArrow / Command-DownArrow, but those go to beginning/end of file in TextMate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> are Universal page up/down on OSX with abridged keyboards.

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>◀</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>▶</kbd> are home and end respectively.

Comment: What do I do when using an external keyboard?

Comment: The option key works in both situations too.